# How to set up aliases for "html import" paths?

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I am recently playing with the Web Components and Polymer, setting up a basic SPA.

I have different custom components, included in my project; my HTML imports look like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../core-icon/core-icon.html">
```

I would like to avoid relavite paths in my imports.

I used to solve the problem by Aliasify, as transform of Browserify, but it doesn't look as a good fit for Web Components.

Anybody can suggest me an alternative?

P.S. I wrote "doesn't look as a good fit for Web Components" because I like the native lazy loading provided by HTML imports (so I don't want to generate a bundle) and also not sure Browserify is happy to process html files.

P.P.S. So my goal would be, for the example above, to define the alias "components" for the folder "some/path/to/components/", to be able to change the import as:

```
<link rel="import" href="components/core-icon/core-icon.html">
```

Comment: When you say in your imports, is that to mean in your component definitions? Or simply in the web page that uses the components?

Comment: At the moment the problem is in my custom components definitions
(but I guess I could experience it also in some pages that I load dynamically by the router).

Comment: What problem? You don't state what problem you are having... just that you don't want relative paths.

Comment: Have relative paths looks like a problem to me. What if I have to change some folder name or move some folders? I don't want to get to open every single component and update its own import. :/

Comment: Have you considered .htaccess, nginx locations, symlinking, or other server-side aliasing/rewrites? There are many such solutions that require no code. What have you tried? Some notes: href resolution is handled by the browser... So without making your own custom component that runs IN the browser or server-side management system that auto-distributes that alias, it's really not possible if you want lazy loading. Finally, there is no way anyone on this site can help you if you don't tell us what you've tried, what works and what hasn't. This is a solutions forum... need to know the problem.

Comment: You might also consider that your "alias" is just a relative path... You just want it to resolve to a different relative path than the one you ask for (hence: alias). Hopefully, given these two comments you can understand my confusion trying to address your issue.

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic sorry for my late answer... your comments made me think more about the problem.

I didn't try too much really, I have seen the problem solved (on a different project) using Browserify with Aliasify and I was looking for an alternative to fit Web Components.

My best solution would be one that I can apply to the frontend, without involving the backend, because I have to ask for changes in the backend to backenders (backend and frontend are completely separated in this project).

I was hoping in an easy way to make "string substitution" on the frontend code, basically...

Answer (score 0):

The answer got pretty easy, once I have started to dig more into Web Components; Vulcanize is a popular tool in the Web Components community and does what I was looking for, check `redirects` in the following example:

```
// example of configuration for Gulp
var vulcanize = require("gulp-vulcanize");
var DEST_DIR = "dist/elements";
var SRC_DIR  = "dist/elements/elements.vulcanized.html";

gulp.task("vulcanize", function () {
    return gulp.src(SRC_DIR)
        .pipe(vulcanize({
            strip: true,
            inlineCss: true,
            inlineScripts: true,
            redirects: [
                "/bower_components|dist/bower_components",
                "/elements|dist/elements"
            ]
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(DEST_DIR))
.pipe($.size({title: "vulcanize"}));
```

Just to make it clear, adopting Vulcanize sadly means no lazy loading